# Python - Cannot upgrade six, issue uninstalling previous version

Tags: python, installation, pip, upgrade, six

When I run `sudo pip install --upgrade six` I run into the issue below:

`2016-01-20 18:29:48|optim $ sudo pip install --upgrade six
    Collecting six
      Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Installing collected packages: six
      Found existing installation: six 1.4.1
    Detected a distutils installed project ('six') which we cannot uninstall. The metadata provided by distutils does not contain a list of files which have been installed, so pip does not know which files to uninstall.`

I have Python 2.7, and I'm on Mac OS X 10.11.1.

How can I make this upgrade successful?

(There are other kind of related posts, but they do not actually have a solution to this same error.)

EDIT:

I am told I can remove `six` manually by removing things from `site-packages`. These are the files in `site-packages` that begin with `six`:

`six-1.10.0.dist-info`, `six-1.9.0.dist-info`, `six.py`, `six.py`.

Are they all correct/safe to remove?

EDIT2:

I decided to remove those from `site-packages`, but it turns out the existing `six` that cannot be installed is actually in
`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`.
There I see the files:
`six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info`, `six.py`, `six.pyc`
but doing `rm` on them (with `sudo`, even) gives `Operation not permitted`.
So *now* the question is, how can I remove *those* files, given where they are?

Comment: You can always go to .../python2.7/site-packages/ and manually remove the folder of the six package.

Comment: Mm, nice. Good call. I thought of that but is there a way to know what to remove manually?

Comment: Yes. Search for the "site-packages" folder and then you should find where your python 2.7 stores its modules. It should be in the form of ..../python2.7/site-packages/  In this folder you will find a subfolder called six and potentially another folder for six egg info. Delete both and that is it.

Comment: I have these files in my site-packages: `six-1.10.0.dist-info`, `six-1.9.0.dist-info`, `six.py`, `six.pyc` Are they all safe to remove?

Comment: Yes, they are. I mean "safe" - you are nuking the six module, so it is as safe as not having a six module can be safe. For example if you have some other packages depending on the six module, then they won't work anymore, but assuming your goal in nuking the six module is to reinstall it immediately, then yes, it is "safe".

Comment: @ZoltanFedor sweet. see my EDIT 2? i just removed those, but turns out the existing `six` is not coming from site-packages. There's another one, but it's not letting me remove.

Comment: Those files in your EDIT 2 are definitely for the SIX package. You should be able to remove them as admin, if not, then the usual filesystem troubleshooting: 1. checking your rights, 2. checking file permissions, 3. checking locks, 4. checking disk integrity, etc. I don't use Mac, so I can't help you with how to get these down on a Mac, but these are standard things you can do in every OS when you want to delete a file and you are not "allowed".

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a known bug in pip 8, which is now being fixed (see  [Change 260150](https://review.openstack.org/#/c/260150/) )

Until this is resolved you can downgrade to pip 7.1.2

Comment: It looks as though it was an intended change in behavior (from warning to fatal error) rather than a bug (see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3384).

Answer (score 1):

I, too, have had some issues with installing modules, and I sometimes find that it helps just to start over. In this case, it looks like you already have some of the 'six' module, but isn't properly set up, so if sudo pip uninstall six yields the same thing, go into your directory and manually delete anything related to six, and then try installing it. You may have to do some digging where you have your modules are stored (or have been stored, as pip can find them in different locations).